# exact string match is not returning true in JavaScript filter helper

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm using a filter helper to create a new array of items that match today's date. I've confirmed that the two comparisons are both a string with a length of 10, yet they're not being recognized as a match when compared in a filter.

I know it has to do with the new Date() method because the first comparison works when I test it against a string of the date while the new Date method does not.

```
if(chosenDate === 'today') {
      // this does not work even though both values are equal
      const scheduled = this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

      // this works
      const scheduled = this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === '2019-11-14');

      // this does not work
      const scheduled = this.props.scheduled.filter(event => '2019-11-14' === new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      console.log(scheduled)
    }

    console.log(this.props.scheduled[0].scheduled_at.substring(0, 10));
    console.log(dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Why is new dates string not comparing equally?

Comment: What is `dateFnsFormat`? Is it even relevant for this question? And why are you passing `'yyyy-MM-dd'` as the second argument to `filter()`?

Comment: It makes it easier to format the date, https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/format.

The second argument formats the date using dateFnsFormat.

Comment: Please include relevant tags and notes in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you meant

```
const scheduled = this.props.scheduled.filter(event =>
  event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
);
```

but wrote

```
const scheduled = this.props.scheduled.filter(event =>
  event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === new Date()
, 'yyyy-MM-dd'
);
```

Comment: Oh my god...that's really dumb of me. Thanks so much for your help!